# How to structure a suite of Unity games to share scripts that have common functionality?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My team is making a suite of games (each in its own Unity project), but there are common functionalities all these games will use:
- loading a specific schema of game parameters over websocket
- accepting a stream of inputs over UDP and parsing the messages

How could I group these games and these shared scripts so that updating the shared scripts results in each game automatically using the new version once the developer pulls from version control?

---

Perhaps is there a way to import a script at run/build time from outside a Unity project but still on the local file system?

Something like this folder structure:

```
/BigRepoOfGames
    SharedFunctionality.cs
    /MyUnityProject1
        /Assets
            /Scripts
                SomeMonoBehavior1.cs # in here, something like `using SharedFunctionality`
    /MyUnityProject2
        /Assets
            /Scripts
                SomeMonoBehavior2.cs # in here, something like `using SharedFunctionality`
```

Comment: You can just make it package https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html

Comment: For importing scripts on runtime requires being able to [compile them at runtime](https://forum.unity.com/threads/compiling-c-at-runtime.376611/). As each Unity project has its own "Project Solution" you can't that simple use code implementation that is shared across projects...

Comment: @caxapexac If I create a local package SharedFunctionality and a project MyUnityProject1, then install the local package SharedFunctionality, then change SharedFunctionality, would those changes reflect in MyUnityProject1? Or would it still be using the version from the time of installing the package?

Comment: @tscizzle there is `Packages/manifest.json` in your projects folder. Just remove `lock` section to update your packages to the last version.